# How to auto generate the next grid after user have selected for the 1st grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I would like to ask how does one do an auto generation of a grid containing a label and a comboBox. What i would like is that once user have selected an option in comboBox1, the method will auto-generate another grid(containing comboBox 2) and so on.

Below is the code i am currently having and right now i am tempted to just create an event driven method to show the next grid once IsSelected is invoked in the current comboBox.

```
 <Grid x:Name="comp1" Margin="0,84,230,345">
            <Label Content="Test Component 1:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="testCompCB1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="207" IsEditable="True" Tag="Test Component" Margin="134,4,0,0"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="comp2" Margin="0,127,230,302" Visibility="Hidden">
            <Label Content="Test Component 2:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="testCompCB2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="207" IsEditable="True" Tag="Test Component" Margin="134,4,0,0"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="comp3" Margin="0,166,230,262" Visibility="Hidden">
            <Label Content="Test Component 3:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="testCompCB3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="207" IsEditable="True" Tag="Test Component" Margin="134,5,0,0"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="comp4" Margin="0,205,230,222" Visibility="Hidden">
            <Label Content="Test Component 4:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="testCompCB4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="207" IsEditable="True" Tag="Test Component" Margin="134,6,0,0"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="comp5" Margin="0,245,230,182" Visibility="Hidden">
            <Label Content="Test Component 5:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="testCompCB5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="207" IsEditable="True" Tag="Test Component" Margin="134,6,0,0"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="comp6" Margin="0,281,230,145" Visibility="Hidden">
            <Label Content="Test Component 6:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,3,0,0"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="testCompCB6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="207" IsEditable="True" Tag="Test Component" Margin="134,10,0,-3"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="comp7" Margin="0,328,230,100" Visibility="Hidden">
            <Label Content="Test Component 7:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="testCompCB7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="207" IsEditable="True" Tag="Test Component" Margin="134,5,0,0"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="comp8" Margin="0,370,230,59" Visibility="Hidden">
            <Label Content="Test Component 8:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="testCompCB8" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="207" IsEditable="True" Tag="Test Component" Margin="134,3,0,0"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="comp9" Margin="0,406,230,15" Visibility="Hidden">
            <Label Content="Test Component 9:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="testCompCB9" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="207" IsEditable="True" Tag="Test Component" Margin="134,12,0,0"/>
        </Grid>
```

Comment: Oo Can you describe your scenario and its usecase, please? Usually I would use a `ListBox` and create a `DataTemplate` as `ListBox.ItemTemplate` to create such a view.

Comment: hi, what i need to do is user for each category, there can be multiple tests for this category. So for a category A, user can choose to add test 1, test 2, test 3 and so on. So when user has selected the item in comboBox 1 in test 1, i would need to automatically generate test 2 containing comboBox 2.

Comment: Hmm, sounds a bit odd or I don't understand your usecase. Wouldn't it be better to implement an *AddItem* view (A `ListBox`, which contains the active selected tests and 2 `Buttons` to add and remove the test from the `ListBox`?

Comment: hi DHN, i solved the problem alr. thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi for those interested in this, i solved it using the follow naive way of procedural coding.

For the xaml:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="testCompList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="274" Margin="10,92,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="361">
            <Canvas x:Name="comp1" Margin="0,0,8,0" Height="26">
                <Label Content="Test Component 1:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <ComboBox x:Name="testComp1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="207" IsEditable="True" Tag="Test Component" Canvas.Left="134" Canvas.Top="5" DropDownClosed="addNewRow"/>
            </Canvas>
            <Canvas x:Name="comp2" Margin="0,0,8,0" Height="26" Visibility="Hidden">
                <Label Content="Test Component 2:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <ComboBox x:Name="testComp2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="207" IsEditable="True" Tag="Test Component" Canvas.Left="134" Canvas.Top="5" DropDownClosed="addNewRow"/>
            </Canvas>
            <Canvas x:Name="comp3" Margin="0,0,8,0" Height="26" Visibility="Hidden">
                <Label Content="Test Component 3:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <ComboBox x:Name="testComp3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="207" IsEditable="True" Tag="Test Component" Canvas.Left="134" Canvas.Top="5" DropDownClosed="addNewRow"/>
            </Canvas>
            <Canvas x:Name="comp4" Margin="0,0,8,0" Height="26" Visibility="Hidden">
                <Label Content="Test Component 4:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <ComboBox x:Name="testComp4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="207" IsEditable="True" Tag="Test Component" Canvas.Left="134" Canvas.Top="5" DropDownClosed="addNewRow"/>
            </Canvas>
            <Canvas x:Name="comp5" Margin="0,0,8,0" Height="26" Visibility="Hidden">
                <Label Content="Test Component 5:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <ComboBox x:Name="testComp5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="207" IsEditable="True" Tag="Test Component" Canvas.Left="134" Canvas.Top="5" DropDownClosed="addNewRow"/>
            </Canvas>
            <Canvas x:Name="comp6" Margin="0,0,8,0" Height="26" Visibility="Hidden">
                <Label Content="Test Component 6:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Top="3"/>
                <ComboBox x:Name="testComp6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="207" IsEditable="True" Tag="Test Component" Canvas.Left="134" Canvas.Top="5" DropDownClosed="addNewRow"/>
            </Canvas>
            <Canvas x:Name="comp7" Margin="0,0,8,0" Height="26" Visibility="Hidden">
                <Label Content="Test Component 7:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <ComboBox x:Name="testComp7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="207" IsEditable="True" Tag="Test Component" Canvas.Left="134" Canvas.Top="5" DropDownClosed="addNewRow"/>
            </Canvas>
            <Canvas x:Name="comp8" Margin="0,0,8,0" Height="26" Visibility="Hidden">
                <Label Content="Test Component 8:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <ComboBox x:Name="testComp8" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="207" IsEditable="True" Tag="Test Component" Canvas.Left="134" Canvas.Top="5" DropDownClosed="addNewRow"/>
            </Canvas>
            <Canvas x:Name="comp9" Margin="0,0,8,0" Height="26" Visibility="Hidden">
                <Label Content="Test Component 9:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <ComboBox x:Name="testComp9" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="207" IsEditable="True" Tag="Test Component" Canvas.Left="134" Canvas.Top="5"/>
            </Canvas>
        </StackPanel>
```

For the code behind:

```
int i = 1;        
private void addNewRow(object sender, EventArgs e) //all will invoke this generic     method to display the visibility of the next
    {
        ComboBox selectedTest = (ComboBox)sender;
        Canvas thisRow = (Canvas)selectedTest.Parent;
        int index =Int32.Parse(thisRow.Name.Substring(thisRow.Name.Length-1, 1));
        if (thisRow is Canvas && index==i) //needs to ensure that only the previous canvas can invoke the next canvas once selection is done
        {
            i++;
            Canvas newRow = (Canvas)this.FindName("comp" + i);
            newRow.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            //add the test Component to a data structure like a list or something

        }

    }
```